# Extract word from a string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string like the following:-
My name is so and so. I am a graduation student. I know c, c++, java and sql server.

How is it possible to extract or split words from this sentence and store it in an array ?

How is it possible to get the output like :- c, c++, java, sql server

### What i did

I loaded a set of strings like "c", "c++", "sql server", "java" into a drop down list. Then I used the following code.

```
string[] wordsinsentence = sentence.Split();//new char[] { ' ',',' ,';','\t','\n', '\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string word in wordsinsentence)
{
    foreach (ListItem li in DropDownList1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Value == word)
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(li.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

The output, will be only "c++" and "java". "sql server" and "c" are not getting saved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because googling `C# split` instantly returns the answer.


Comment: The lack of any research efforts and understanding about the problem being solved here is scaring.

Comment: This will help you [Split](https://www.google.ae/search?noj=1&biw=1920&bih=976&q=split+string+c%23&oq=split+str&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l10.8757.10399.0.11726.9.9.0.0.0.0.398.1729.2j4j1j2.9.0....0...1c.1.25.serp..3.6.967.xdssDMqRPDU)

Comment: I researched on that. I could get it split based on blank spaces, periods, ':', etc ; which means I can get the output like : c, c++, java, sql, server.

Comment: @user2625672 I think you should be searching a string for particular tags like `c`, `c++`, etc. If you have a string with a comma in it that doesn't have anything to do with a language, like this one, your result won't be correct.

Comment: @user2625672: The question is still not clear. However, there are two likely reasons why you get a undesired result: 1.)`==` compares case-sensitive, so `C` and `c` are different 2.) you split also `sql server`, so if the `ListItem.Value` is `"sql server"` it does not match `"sql"` or `"server"`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : That is my problem.... The one you mentioned about "sql server".

Comment: @user2625672: Have  a look at my edited answer. Maybe a substring search is sufficient: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18447268/284240

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is using [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) without parameters:

```
string[] words = text.Split();
```

> If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters,
>   [white-space characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx) are assumed to be the delimiters.

**Edit** according to your last edit and my comment on it:

> you split also sql server, so if the ListItem.Value is "sql server" it
>   does not match "sql" or "server"

You:

> That is my problem.... The one you mentioned about "sql server".

You could use `Contains` or (if you want to compare case-insensitive) `IndexOf`:

```
string sentence = "My name is so and so. I am a graduation student. I know c, c++, java and sql server.";
string[] words = sentence.Split();

var matchingItems = DropDownList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(li => words.Any(w => li.Text.IndexOf(w, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
foreach(ListItem item in matchingItems)
    DropDownList2.Items.Add(item.Text);
```

Comment: -1 spoon-feeding a question like this encourages the user to do it again.

Comment: @user2625672: It's a linq query, but you could also use a simple loop if you are not familiar with it. The important part is `Text.IndexOf...` since that returns the index where a given substring was found(one of the words). If it was not found the method returns `-1`, that's why i have checked `>= 0`. If you don't need to compare case-insensitive you could replace `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` with `StringComparison.Ordinal` or simply replace the `IndexOf` with `Contains`.

Comment: I found a problem with this query. When I run the code, it returns all the strings stored in the database. I think comparison is not happening.

Comment: I don't see an obvious Bug. Are you sure that the result is wrong, have you used the debugger? Maybe you have a single character linke C as Word.

Comment: Definitely, there is "C" and "sql server". 
What happens is that, every item that is displayed in DropDownList1 is shown in DropDownList2.

Comment: @user2625672: What words are in `DropDownList1`? In your sample senetence are multiple one-character words and other short words. Compare the `string[] words` and each item in the `DropDownList`. My approach searches inside the item's text. So if the text is "java" and one word is `a` you have a match since `s` is in "java". Is that desired or not? Maybe you want to compare the whole word instead. So for example: `Item.Text="sql server"` and word `sql` since that is a word in the string `sql server`. That's a different approach. You see, you need to define your requirement precisely.

Comment: Okay,my database table values are:- C, C++, Java, SQL Server. The string that I have is:- Hello, my name is so ans so. I know C and SQL Server". So, the oputput that I should get is C and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how complex you want to make this, easy way would be to simply split on space characters

```
"My name is so and so.".Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You could remove first any other characters like points or commas via some regex if that is required.